# domain whois record does not display expiry date

Tags: domains, whois

I came accross a domain ending with ".ai" TLD. Ran the whois query for that domain, but the result did not show the expiry data, though it showed the creation date and other fields. I also have personally another domain registered with the same registrar (namecheap). When I query my own domain it shows the expiry date also. What is the reason for that.

Thanks

Comment: What is the domain name?

Answer (score 1):

The info provided by Whois is not always the same, it depends on what the Whois database for that particular TLD returns.

Some return the expiration date, some return the nameservers, etc. Some don't. It should be standardized imo, but nothing to do there.

It seems like the .ai database doesn't return the expiration date within the Whois query as odd as it seems.

It's strange, but it is what it is.

Keep in mind that the .ai TLD is a country code TLD, which means it is "owned" or managed by an actual geographical government: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ai

Usually this kind of TLD's are more prone to irregularities as this one.